# jQuery onload function

Tags: jquery

I m using the following script to call a onload function but it does not works in IE

`("#body").attr({onload : "calFact();"});`

Answer (score 23):

If you are using jQuery you could use the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function like so:

```
$(function() {
  callFact();
});
```

or even more simply, just pass the method to jQuery:

```
$(callFact);
```

That will fire as soon as the DOM is available to manipulate, sometimes earlier than `onload`.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot set onload event handlers on anything other than the window. (Well, you can, but it will have no effect.) If you want `calFact` to run at the onload event, you should use `$(window).load(calFact);`. But generally it is more useful to call things at the DOMready event: `$(document).ready(calFact);` or just `$(calFact);` for short. The difference is that onload happens when everything loaded (including images, which are slow to load), and DOMready happens when the DOM tree is loaded (but images not necessarily yet).

Also, there is not much point in assigning an id of `body` to the body when there is only one of it anyway; you can just use `$('body')`.

Comment: IFRAME fire onload event too... ;-)

Comment: True, and generally elements with an `src` attribute (such as `object`, `applet`, `embed`, `script`...) do.

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably want to do this instead:

```
$('#body').ready(function(){
    calFact();
});
```

Comment: gnarf's answer is definitely best if your calFact() is not targeted to a specific DOM element as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use ready()

More at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thank you very much for all answers.
Invoking function in document ready works !!!

Comment: Actually all the answers were true :)