# Execute a javascript function as last inside a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be sure that a certain script within a page is executed as last.
I thought of using JQuery

```
$(document).ready( ... )
```

but if there are more functions of this type, which is actually executed last?

Comment: jQuery event handlers are executed in the order that they're bound, though that only helps you if you can guarantee that your event handler will be bound last, and that there aren't any event handlers bound for events that fire later (such as `load`).

Comment: Take a look at this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3623967/90011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to delay the execution of a script.

There is no way to programatically detect all of them.

For a reliable solution you would have to reverse engine the code of each page you care about, figure out what it is doing (and when) and write your delay script specifically for that page. (For a value of "reliable" equal to "until they change the page").

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the order in which you have registered them.

E.g:

```
$(document).ready( function() { alert("first"); });
$(document).ready( function() { alert("second"); });
$(document).ready( function() { alert("third"); });​
```

would alert "first" then "second" then "third"

So adding a `<script>` to the bottom of your page with an `$(document).ready( yourfunction );` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready( ... )
```

is not executed last. The last function executed ( so, after document ready ) is the one(s) from `<body onload>`.

Example : `<body onload="myJSfunction();">`

Here, the javascript `myJSfunction` is executed at the end, after $(document).ready( ... ).

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you can do something like this:

```
// Form array of functions which sould be called with according order
$.readyArray = [function () { ... }, function () { ... }, function () { ... }, ...];

// just execute them in this order when onready event
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $.readyArray.length; i++) {
    //apply, calls function in current context and pass arguments object
    $.readyArray[i].apply(this,[arguments]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If refactoring (as [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155771/900880) suggested) is not an option (e.g. you are updating a just part of a framework or a product), you can use four approaches, which should give you a good chance achieving what you need. See the following snippets with jQuery:

**(1) Wait until 'document' is ready**

By document is meant the visible DOM. The script will fire when all it should be rendered really rendered is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Document is ready.');
});
```

**(2) Wait until top-level JS (Root) 'window' object is ready**

The full root object can (will) be ready some time after the DOM is ready.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  console.log('Window is ready.');
});
```

**(3) Wait until 'window' is fully loaded using .bind**

This fires immediately after 'window' is ready, so your script can act on objects (elements) rendered during `$(window).ready()` above.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  console.log('Window bind is ready.');
});
```

**(4) Wait until Ajax calls are completed**

This is as far as you can go - the script will fire when 'window' is ready, loaded, all the code run and all the Ajax actions are completed. Unfortunately, since one Ajax can call another one, it can fire several times during the page load.

```
$(window).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log('Window bind is ready, Ajax finished.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple Javascript solution, you could call the javascript function at end of your HTML document inside the script tag. This works well when you are not using jQuery.

In case of jQuery you could use load method.The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded.

For more info look at

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    //code here
});
```